# Can we pull messages from GCP Pub/Sub subscription over Interconnect?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-interconnect

It is feasible to pull messages from GCP Pub/Sub subscription over public Internet by reaching to the public GCP Pub/Sub API endpoint.

However, is it feasible to pull messages over the GCP dedicated Interconnect for more stable network connection? I would like to reduce the workload of proxy for reaching Public Internet by going through the private dedicated Interconnect channel.

Comment: You still have network routing to perform, but not to go outside, to stay in the network. The documentation and the Kristen answer can help you on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP provide private access options for private routing. One of the example that suits the use case is the private service connect endpoint.

A private endpoint is deployed in the GCP project. On-premise host can access google API via this endpoint through VPC or Interconnect access, instead of the public API endpoint, such that the traffic can avoid exposing in the public Internet.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the docs on service APIs overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview), which explain that:

> Requests to the global endpoint made over Interconnect are routed similarly to requests originating in the region associated with the interconnection. In case Pub/Sub becomes unavailable in a region, requests originating within the same Google Cloud region are not load balanced to a different region.